# Using Linux on SSD and HDD for Data/Programs

Tags: software-installation, ssd, home, external-hdd

I have been researching this for quite some time coming from Windows that there is no “Path” that you can give to a program during installation, but instead the program downloads where it needs to.

Is there a way on Linux based systems that instead of filling up/installing on the Main SSD (with the OS) the program installs on a separate data drive?

The only solution seems to move the home directory and some other directories? What are those other directories that would need to be moved and how would that be done? Would I mount them somewhere else or use mv?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, installing manually (`configure` + `make install`) allows you to choose where to install. some UNIX dinosaurs like me still grew up installing on `/opt` and you still could do.

Using a packet manager like `apt` or `rpm` leads you to rely on given install paths. As you suggest, you can move a directory structure to a different drive and mount that drive to the original place:

```
sudo mv /opt/* /dev/sdx
sudo mount /dev/sdx /opt
```

But better don't do that with something like `/usr`, because (1) there are very basic things and you probably want to keep your system functional if your hdd gets corrupted and (2) there are executables and libraries you want to load fast.

So you move things to your hdd that are not essential, but huge and don't need to load fast. And then you don't mount them individually, but use symbolic links:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdx /bigdrive
mv ~/Movies /bigdrive
ln -s /bigdrive/Movies ~
```

Use something like `du -sm *|sort -n` to identify what is worth to be moved.